# Did people in other Yugas live on any other planet(s)?

Tags: yuga

Scientists discovered 8 planets till now. Other than earth, did people in other Yugas like satya yuga, trethayuga & dwaparayuga live on any other planet?

Comment: No I believe. If so than obviously there should have been a discovery of it just like the discovery of the planets. Right?

Comment: When Krishna showed his Virap form to Arjuna, then he got fear by seeing it and asked who are you? Krishna replied and in one of his talk he said, as per my wish crores of galaxies are being made and destroyed. Whenever I wish made it and whenever I wish I destroyed it. So by this talk of Krishna we can conclude that he not only created this galaxy but countless galaxies in which life must have been present, Else why would they create a galaxy if he don't wanna spread life in it. There are tons of galaxies out there where we can't reach. Space is endless, u cant cover endless with telescope.